# Ergonomics of a Metal Storm Staff Gun

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, engineering, firearms, ergonomics

Upon the The Peaks of Comprehension lies the the Temple of Knowledge, where monks labor, record, observe and preserve knowledge both old and new.  With the knowledge they have gained, the monks go out to the lands below and act as teachers and advisors to those they deem worthy, but otherwise guard their findings with jealousy.

Shame that the bloodthirsty warmongers don't the hint!

So, to defend themselves, the monks have come up with a weapon that struck true with the old ways while having the fire power of modern day firearms.  The Metal Storm Gun Staff!  Which...has more than one issue with it.

Poor attempt in Worldbuilding/Story telling aside, the idea of using the [Metal Storm concept](https://futurewarstories.blogspot.com/2018/01/fws-armory-metal-storm-by-yoel.html) to fit a gun inside a pole like weapon is a rather cool and entertaining one.  However, the issue is the it is extremely difficult to have both a stock, trigger and sighting system built into the shaft when the ability to move your hands up and down said shaft is paramount in combat.

So in short, **what design could the creators of such a weapon use to at least mitigate the ergonomic issues of such a weapon.**

Basically, can they fit a trigger, butt stock and sighting system that is half way decent?

Some assumptions:

-Ignore the loading issue

-Smart links are not allowed.  The hyper conservative monk faction are very animate about that bit.

-Assume the shaft/barrel can handle the stress of being struck and having bullets shot out of it.

P.S. The monk bit is there to have a bit of fun, don't take it to seriously for the question.

Answer (score 3):

I really like this idea, let’s explore it!

Firstly we need to consider if we need a stock and sights. You may notice a significant number of firearms do not have a stock, we call these pistols. Something absolutely crucial for you to consider is how the weapons are used. How do your monks use these weapons in combat? Are they staffs with a metal storm gun in them or are they metal storm guns that double as staffs? The distinction may seem small, but it is important. If it is primarily a staff then it needs to be optimized as a melee weapon which also shoots bullets, but if it’s primarily a metal storm gun then it needs to be optimized for range while still being able to be used in a melee.

If it is primarily a staff then we don’t need a stock because it will be used at close range. As for sights, you will only need a small front sight on the end the bullets come out. You put the front sight on the target and fire. As for a trigger, this is pretty simple and is the same for both configurations. Have the front hand squeeze or push some kind of safety while the rear hand pulls a small trigger. This way the controls are small enough that they won’t interfere and you won’t accidentally shoot yourself while practicing.

If you want it to primarily be a ranged weapon, I would advocate a fold out approach. The bottom 8 inches of the staff flips 90 degrees and forms a stock, and the sights flip up from the side of the staff. The firing controls remain the same. This would suffer slightly in melee combat as the moving parts would be vulnerable to damage and could break, but it would still work.

So there’s two ideas for you, remember to practice gun-staff safety. The life you save may be your own.

Answer (score 1):

The butt stock is a hook that is midway along the staff.
You hold / aim it something like a [LAWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M72_LAW) rocket, with the staff going over your shoulder, and both your hands gripping around the front half of the staff, and the aformentioned hook pressed into your shoulder.
Sights come off the staff at a 45-degree angle to the horizontal, instead of being straight up and down.
As far as trigger, one hand squeezes a "grip safety," which prevents the staff from being discharged accidentally, the other hand operates the controls.